# Nested If/Else/End If within Select Case

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel 2010 form. I am trying to change the row color based on several variables.

I do understand that this can be accomplished with conditional formatting and have got that to work, but cutting and pasting, as my users will likely do, kills the formatting. I was hoping that VBA would fix that. Possibly there is some other solution I am unaware of.

This is what I want to happen (the so called logic)

```
 on Sheet3  
 Columns (a – w)  
 rows (2 – 10485)  
 upon a change in any field, $x2, or a past due date in $T2

if(AND($X2="Open",$T2<>"",$T2<=TODAY()) then all row red ($a2-$x2)
if(AND($X2="Open",$T2="",$T2>TODAY()) then all row white ($a2-$x2)
=$X2="Completed" then all row grey ($a2-$x2)
=$X2="Rescinded" then $X2 = orange and $A2 thru $W2 = grey
```

The `x` field will use a drop down and be either ( blank, open, completed, or rescinded )

This is the code I have tried to hobble together and failed with.....

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Intersect(Target, Range("A2:X1048567")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
     Select Case Cells(Target.Row, "X").Value
     Case "Open"
     If Cells(Target.Row, "T").Value <> "" And T2 <= TODAY() Then 'Range(Cells(Target.Row, "A"), Cells(Target.Row, "F")).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
     Else
     Range(Cells(Target.Row, "A"), Cells(Target.Row, "F")).Interior.ColorIndex = x1None
     End Select

     Case "Completed"
     Range(Cells(Target.Row, "A"), Cells(Target.Row, "F")).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
     Case "Rescinded"
     Range(Cells(Target.Row, "A"), Cells(Target.Row, "F")).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
     Range(Cells(Target.Row, "A"), Cells(Target.Row, "F")).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
     Case ""
     Range(Cells(Target.Row, "A"), Cells(Target.Row, "F")).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
     End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a few discrepancies between what you described and what your code sample indicated so I went with the former.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:X")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim rw As Long, rng As Range
        For Each rng In Intersect(Target, Range("A:X"))
            rw = rng.Row
            If rw > 1 Then
                Select Case LCase(Cells(rw, "X").Value2)
                    Case "open"
                        If Cells(rw, "T").Value <> "" And Cells(rw, "T").Value <= Date Then
                            Cells(rw, "A").Resize(1, 24).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                        Else
                            Cells(rw, "A").Resize(1, 24).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
                        End If
                    Case "completed"
                        Cells(rw, "A").Resize(1, 24).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                    Case "rescinded"
                        Cells(rw, "A").Resize(1, 23).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                        Cells(rw, "X").Interior.ColorIndex = 46
                    Case Else
                        Cells(rw, "A").Resize(1, 24).Interior.Pattern = xlNone 'use pattern to turn off interior fill
                End Select
            End If
        Next rng
    End If
safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

That should also handle multiple entries like those received from pasting a number of values into the sheet. By 'white' I assumed that you meant to remove any fill color, not actually provide a white fill color.