# Color non-adjacent cells that match criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I use the below code to color the cells in column K and Z that match the criteria; but it colors all cells between K and Z. To fix, I use the last line of code to remove the color in columns L thru Y. Is there a way to modify the line of code that starts with "Range" to only color cells K and Z that match the criteria?

```
Sub ColrCls()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("K" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lRow
            If .Cells(i, 11).Value = "Non Sen" And .Cells(i, 26).Value = "N/A" Then
            Range(.Cells(i, 11), .Cells(i, 26)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        Next i

        Columns("L:Y").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: In my opinion you don't even need Vba. Did you try conditional formatting?

Comment: I would prefer vba, because I will be adding 4 or 5 additional IF statements. Clearing columns L thru Y is sloppy, but I don't know how to fix the Range line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying the [Range.Parent property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980.aspx) in your [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) but ignoring it when it is most important¹.

```
Sub ColrCls()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("K" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lRow
            If .Cells(i, 11).Value = "Non Sen" And .Cells(i, 26).Value = "N/A" Then
                .Range("K" & i & ", Z" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            Else
                .Range("K" & i & ", Z" & i).Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

A [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) to [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621.aspx) discontiguous cells could be one of the following.

```
.Range("K5, Z5")
Union(.Cells(5, "K"), .Cells(5, "Z"))
```

In the example above, I've concatenated together a string like the first of these two examples.

---

¹ <sub>See **[Is the . in .Range necessary when defined by .Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368220/is-the-in-range-necessary-when-defined-by-cells)** for an earnest discussion on this subject.</sub>

Comment: btw, you might need an `Else` to clear the interior colorindex if K and Z do not meet the conditions but did on a previous run through. In this case you would use `.Range("K" & i & ", Z" & i).Interior.Pattern = xlNone`.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped, I will test your code tomorrow at work. I will get back with you tomorrow with what i find out. I will also read the information about .Range.

Comment: I check your fix on some mock data and it work perfectly, Thank you.

Comment: For *'4 or 5 additional IF statements'* you may want to swtich the method to a [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx). See **[Conditional Formatting VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319443/conditional-formatting-vba/38319605#38319605)**.

Answer (score 2):

You could replace

```
Range(.Cells(i, 11), .Cells(i, 26)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
```

with

```
.Cells(i, 11).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
.Cells(i, 26).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
```

Comment: your input worked fine, i just prefer Jeeped's input. Thanks for the input.